# GWT Locale change

Tags: gwt, locale

I use gwt and I want to use translate language. I added this line in my .xml file

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="ro"/>
<set-property name="locale" value="ro"/>
```

and also at my url end I added &locale=ro but nothing happens.
What do I need to do next in order for it to work? Romanian is listed in the list of translated languages for the api so I thought this is enough. Do I need to provide other files other than what I have now?

P.S.:I tried it after [Localizing StockWatcher](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read the docs: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n#DevGuideStaticStringInternationalization
Notice the part where they talk about properties files there.

From the tutorial you reference, please read https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n#international